# Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object not found

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr, lubridate

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
    iden date      
  <dbl> <date>    
1     1 2011-02-21
2     2 2013-03-11
3     3 NA        
4     4 NA
```

I am trying to execute the below command

```
 data <- data %>%
      map(c(test, delta), as.name) %>%
      setNames(c("test", "delta"))
```

But I get the below error

> Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'iden' not found

However, when I re-write the above command like below, I get the output as shown below

```
map(c(data$test, data$delta),as.name)
```

1. May I know why the code doesn't work with the `%>%` operator?
2. May I know why the date value is changed to the number in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear what you are trying to do here but to answer your questions -

> 1. May I know why the code doesn't work with the %>% operator

Because this is how pipes work. The left hand side of pipe is the first argument to the function on right hand side. So when you do

```
data %>% map(c(iden, date),as.name)
```

you are actually doing :

```
map(data, c(iden, date),as.name)
```

which returns the same error.

> Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'iden' not found`

---

For the second question :

> May I know why the date value is changed to the number in the output?

I don't know the *why* but dates are internally stored as number of days since `1970-01-01` which can be verified by changing the dates to numbers.

```
as.numeric(data$date)
#[1] 15026 15775    NA    NA
```

The output that you get are the similar numbers.

Comment: Hi Ronak! Thanks for the response. Upvoted. I posted few more lines of code

Comment: `map(data, c(iden, date),as.name)` is incorrect since `?map` expects 1st argument as data and the 2nd argument as function. Here you are passing 3 arguments which is why you get an error. To apply `as.name` on both the column you can use `map` like `map(names(data), as.name)`